# passing on object using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi have the following function which works fine:

```
        jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').click(function(obj){                
           jQuery(this).closest('li').fadeOut(400, function() { $(this).remove(); }); // This works
        });
```

On this HTML code:

```
<li id="listItem_dsc_6440.jpg"> 
    <div class="buttonPanel">
        <span title="Delete image" class="btnRemoveItem floatRight" id="dsc_6440.jpg"> </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

This fades down the list item, then removes it.
Now I'm adding a `jQuery.post` and I need to put the fadeout / remove inside this .post

```
        jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').click(function(obj){

            jQuery.post("wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/adm_gallery.php", { deleteImage: 'single', name: jQuery(this).attr('id') },
            function(data){
                if(data.status == 'deleted');
                {
                    jQuery(obj).closest('li').fadeOut(400, function() { $(this).remove(); });
                }
            }, "json");
         });
```

Of course, this doesn't work. I'm pretty sure it's because I don't know what `obj` is - and how I can use it.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `this` in a local variable. Like this:

```
    jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').click(function(){
        var obj = this; //reference to the button
        jQuery.post("wp-content/themes/storelocator/include/adm_gallery.php", { deleteImage: 'single', name: jQuery(this).attr('id') },
        function(data){
            if(data.status == 'deleted');
            {
                jQuery(obj).closest('li').fadeOut(400, function() { $(obj).remove(); });
            }
        }, "json");
     });
```

The callback function of post forms a closure and it can 'see' the local variables of the outer function.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of click() method is the event object, so you can use the target property

```
jQuery(obj.target).closest('li').fadeOut(...);
```

or just define a helper variable inside the click handler that holds the reference to the element

```
jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').click(function(obj){
   var element = this;

   jQuery.post(...
      function(data){
         if(data.status == 'deleted'){
            jQuery(element).closest('li').fadeOut(...);
         },
      }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to work around this would be to have your 'delete' page, when returning a JSON response, **also** return the ID/other identifying attribute for the object that was deleted. Then, you can just do `jQuery('#' + data.object_id)` to find the object you need to remove.

Typically, I do this using IDs like object-1, object-2, etc. - and then my code just looks for `#object-[foo]` when retrieving an item in the HTML to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `obj` is the button you clicked at then I suppose you can replace `jQuery(obj).closest('li')` in the 2nd function with something like `jQuery('.btnRemoveItem').closest('li')`

Comment: Your solution would work when only one .btnRemoveItem element existed. If there are more elements with given className, your solution would affect all.

Comment: I have about 15 `.btnRemoveItem` ;o)

Comment: yep - if there more than one then assigning local var to `this` will work

Answer (score 0):

Does this error occur even when you remove the last parameter of "post" (which is currently "json")? Sometimes, when return type is different than the expected, the callback method is never called.